# ¿Como leer un Properties externo?

Tags: java, archivo-de-propiedades

Tengo un programa [jar](/questions/tagged/jar) que corro en un servidor diariamente, para que tome ciertos valores, desde la url de una base de datos, direcciones de carpetas etc.

Tengo un archivo de tipo `properties` dentro del proyecto, el problema que presento, es que tengo que cambiar y agregar constantemente mas variables, y me resulta tedioso compilar y modificar el codigo desde el IDE, y subirlo para remplazar el anterior.

Lo que necesito es leerlo externamente, y asi solamente cambiar el archivo por fuera sin necesidad de tenerlo compilado dentro del proyecto.

Comment: Un JAR es a fin de cuentas un ZIP, por lo que puedes extraer el properties, editarlo y volver a meterlo al jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si actualmente lees tu archivo `properties` sacando la ruta al mismo con `getResourceAsStream`, tendrías que usar uno de los métodos que ya pusieron en las otras respuestas, donde lees de un archivo externo. El problema es tener la ruta completa a dicho archivo.

Incluso puedes combinar el contenido del archivo interno con el de un archivo externo:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
try (InputStream ins = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dentro/del/zip.properties")) {
    p.load(ins);
}
File f = new File("ruta/al/externo.properties);
if (f.exists() && f.canRead()) {
    try(FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream(f)) {
        p.load(ins);
    }
}
```

De ese modo cargas el archivo interno con defaults y solamente si existe el archivo externo, lo cargas también, cargando así valores nuevos y sobreescribiendo lo que venga del archivo dentro del JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo que puedes hacer es tener una clase Util en la que leas el archivo properties , ahí indicas la ruta, posterior a hacerle load, solo con getProperty deberás obtener las propiedades que desees utilizar.
Te muestro un ejemplo y espero sea lo que buscas.

```
//Bloque en tu clase java para leer un arcvhivo externo
static {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        prop = new Properties();
        //indica la ruta donde se encuentra  el archivo properties
        fis = new FileInputStream("/ruta/ruta/ruta/miArvhivoProp.properties");
        //leer archivo properties
        prop.load(fis);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Fallo procesando archivo miArvhivoProp.properties.", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Fallo cerrando archivo miArvhivoProp.properties.", e);
        }
    }
}
//metodo para retornar una propiedad que se encuentre en el archivo properties
public static String parametro(String propiedad) {
    return (String)prop.getProperty(propiedad);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) :

```
Properties pop = new Properties();
pop.load(new FileInputStream("mis_properties.properties"));
pop.put("NUEVA_PROPIEDAD", "NUEVO_VALOR");
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("mis_properties.properties");
pop.store(output, "Editando el archivo properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hasta el momento, esta es la mejor manera que he encontrado, es necesario crear un método por cada variable:

```
public String getDestiny() throws IOException
    {
        String valor = null;
        Properties archivoPropertie = new Properties();
        FileInputStream archivo;
        String ruta = "./serverProps.properties"; //Se debe guardar en la misma ruta del JAR
        archivo = new FileInputStream(ruta);
        archivoPropertie.load(archivo);
        archivo.close();
        valor = archivoPropertie.getProperty("destiny");
        return valor;
    }
```

Para mandarlo a llamar solo se haria de la siguiente manera:

```
    try
    {
         String dstvalor = getDestiny();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```