# ¿Cual es la ruta a utilizar para acceder a un archivo .properties en java?

Tags: java, archivo, java-ee, maven, configuración

Tengo un proyecto Web Java y estoy usando Maven, he colocado en src/main/resources un archivo "configuraciones.properties", he intentado acceder a el de diferentes maneras y ninguna me funciona.

¿Cual es la manera de acceder al archivo?, actualmente mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
propiedades.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("configuraciones.properties"));
```

¿Es correcto ubicar el archivo properties dentro de "src/main/resources"?

Comment: Es el lugar correcto y lo estás pidiendo de la manera correcta... ¿te da un NotFoundException? Deberías añadir el stacktrace

Comment: Hola Pablo Lozano, el error que me muestra es el siguiente:ADVERTENCIA:   StandardWrapperValve[org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

bueno ahí varias maneras de leer properties,  si quieres tu archivo dentro o fuera del proyecto, mirando tu codigo que que le falta un "/"

prueba de esta manera

```
propiedades.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/configuraciones.properties"));
```

en el siguiente enlaces puede ver como leer un archivo externo

[leer properties externo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33215/como-leer-un-propertie-externo)

saludos

Comment: Ya añadi el "/" en la cadena pero aun asi me muestra el mismo error.   ADVERTENCIA:   StandardWrapperValve[org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Estimado, consulta es una aplicacion con sprint? o que framework estas usando?

Comment: Hola, no estoy utilizando ningun framework, es jee puro. Pero no entiendo el porque del error si he visto en todo los tutoriales que de esa manera abren los archivos.

Comment: si gustas subes tu proyecto algún lugar y lo reviso saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si sería bueno que pusieras todo el stacktrace.

A mi me funciona así:

```
    Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
    ClassLoader contextClassLoader = currentThread.getContextClassLoader();
    URL resource = contextClassLoader.getResource("configuraciones.properties");

    if (resource == null) {
        //Creo mi propia clase de excepciones para este caso 
        throw new ConfigurationException("No existe el recurso configuraciones.properties');
    }

    try (InputStream is = resource.openStream()) {
        properties.load(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ConfigurationException(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Esta es la ruta que donde se encuentra tu properties.

[image]
Este es mi properties.

Lo que hago es llamar con su primer nombre que es Vistas y luego llamar a cualquier de estas varibles con el mensaje que quiero que ejecute. Ojala te ayude.

**ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Vistas").getString("DetalleInformacion_1Updated");**

[image]